# Ajuda na lógica de condições e repetição em C++

Tags: c++, loop, lógica, condição

Tenho o seguinte código de verificação para saber se um determinado número pertence a um vetor. Eu não consegui pensar numa maneira mais precisa de fazer com que o programa diga que o número NÃO pertence ao vetor, apenas que pertence e qual a sua posição dentro do mesmo. Podem me ajudar a fazer com que seja exibida a mensagem "o número não faz parte do vetor", após a verificação? (de um jeito mais enxuto)

Código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int vetor[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int N;
    cout << "digite um numero: " << endl;
    cin >> N;

    for(int i = 0; i <=4; i++)
    {
        if(N == vetor[i])
            cout << "O numero faz parte do vetor e está na " << i+1 << " posicao" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode controlar isso com uma variável `achou` que começa como `false` e quando ele acha o número procurado, muda para `true`. Depois do `for`, se a variável `achou` for `false` é porque o número não estava no vetor.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int vetor[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int n;
    cout << "Digite um número: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    bool achou = false;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (n == vetor[i]) {
            cout << "O número " << n << " faz parte do vetor e está na posição " << (i + 1) << "." << endl;
            achou = true;
        }
    }

    if (!achou) {
        cout << "O número " << n << " não faz parte do vetor." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Um outro detalhe a se notar é que se um mesmo número aparecer mais de uma vez dentro do vetor, ele mostrará a mensagem que encontrou para cada ocorrência. Caso esse comportamento não for o desejado, basta acrescentar um `break;` logo após o `achou = true;`.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](http://ideone.com/qBJUgz)

Comment: Eu tinha pensado em usar outro if, mas não sabia como. Foia boa demais essa explicação, até porque eu não sabia como usar variáveis do tipo boolean. Obrigado Victor Stafusa!